# Error during installion of Jolie

Tags: jolie

Error during the installion of Jolie.
I see the following message after the execution of

```
$ java -jar jolie-1.4.1.jar
```

> [Windows_installer.ol] Thrown unhadled fault: FileNotFound
>
> [installer.ol] Internale server error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer needs permission to write in the directories in which you intend to install Jolie. That error typically shows up when the installer is launched from a terminal without administrator privileges.

Did you launch the installer from a [Command Prompt as an Administrator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, you are right. As administrator it works. Thanks.